# Upload document into excel via vba based on doc name

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, file-upload

I wrote below code, this code upload all document from share drive into excel based on their naming convention.

However it's applicable for Pdf file only. can you please help me that how can i upload other ext file as well like outlook/word/excel?

```
Dim folderPath As String, fileName As String
Dim destCell As Range

With Worksheets("ABC")
folderPath = .Range("F7").Value
Set destCell = .Range("G12")
End With

If Right(folderPath, 1) <> "\" Then folderPath = folderPath & "\"

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
fileName = Dir(folderPath & "ABC*.pdf")
Do While fileName <> vbNullString
destCell.Worksheet.OLEObjects.Add _
fileName:=folderPath & fileName, _
Link:=False, _
DisplayAsIcon:=True, _
IconFilename:="C:\windows\Installer\{AC76BA86-1033-F400-7760-000000000005}\_PDFFile.ico", _
IconIndex:=0, _
IconLabel:=fileName, _
Left:=destCell.Left, _
Top:=destCell.Top, _
Width:=150, _
Height:=5
Set destCell = destCell.Offset(, 1)
fileName = Dir
Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox "Document Uploaded Successfully..!!"
```

Answer (score 0):

Something Like This?

```
Dim folderPath As String, fileName As String
Dim destCell As Range

With Worksheets("ABC")
folderPath = .Range("F7").Value
Set destCell = .Range("G12")
End With

If Right(folderPath, 1) <> "\" Then folderPath = folderPath & "\"

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
fileName = Dir(folderPath & "ABC*.*")
Do While fileName <> vbNullString
destCell.Worksheet.OLEObjects.Add _
fileName:=folderPath & fileName, _
Link:=False, _
DisplayAsIcon:=True, _
IconFilename:="C:\windows\Installer\{AC76BA86-1033-F400-7760-000000000005}\_PDFFile.ico", _
IconIndex:=0, _
IconLabel:=fileName, _
Left:=destCell.Left, _
Top:=destCell.Top, _
Width:=150, _
Height:=5
Set destCell = destCell.Offset(, 1)
fileName = Dir
Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox "Document Uploaded Successfully..!!"
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It's working. However what about the document icon? by this code only pdf icon is visible . what about other?

Comment: Hmm it is more complicated.  If you use changed IconFileName for example: `IconFilename:="", _`   file don't show any icon (Show Only Name of file). If You need icon try this: https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/code-to-insert-file-attachment-as-icon-to-defined-cell.1033645/post-4961840